# Android Studio Layout is not Responding

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently have added a layout and a java file connecting it to my java code file which is taking and giving actual output by implementing an algorithm but the second layout when opened in my phone it does not react to any of the two buttons clicked on it.
Seems like an error in AndroidManifest file.
here is Manifest file code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplicationgeneric">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/jug_black_trasnparent"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/jug_black_trasnparent"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Next"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".connectorclass">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.Calculator"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
</manifest>
```

here connectorclass.java is linked to the Layout not Responding named something xyz..

Comment: your question is not clear and need to be add more detail with code.

Comment: Please show how do you *connect* problematic layout with your java code

Answer (score 0):

you can remove

`<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.Calculator"/>
        </intent-filter>`

in android manifest and can start activity  using class name by default
like this

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, connectorclass.class);
           startActivity(intent);`

try this

Comment: i tried it, its not working. Maybe any other part is faulted.

Comment: Thank you so much nayan sardar & yousef. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the intent filter for "connectorclass".

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file, you provide two intent files. That doesn't need it. Always try to add one `intent-filter` on your activity and this activity is your lancer activity. So remove the second `intent-filter` from `connectorclass activity`. 
Then add below code on your button `onClickListener`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.class, connectorclass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```